# how can i keep the text in buttons programmatically in custom cell ? by using JSon Parser?

Tags: ios

How to keep the text in buttons and that text i am getting by using JSON parser.like Option1,option2,option3 like this.what can i do?

**I am writing like this.**

```
cell.lab1.text = [_ans1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lab2.text = [_ans2Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: What's the meaning of "keep the text in buttons", is the text out of the border or you just want to persistent the text?

Comment: text printing on button.